# Download exe file for TeX Live 2016 and 2015 for windows

Tags: distributions, texlive-2016, texlive-2017

Basically I want to find a link to actually download the exe file for windows for TeX Live 2015 and 2016... I cannot find any !! TeX Live 2017 seems incompatible at the moment for me since that wget.exe is unable to run at my computer so installation is frozen !! Unless there is a way to overcome that !!

Comment: See 'historic' versions of TL here in order to download either tarballs or the iso file ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/

Comment: So I need to download the .iso file ?

Comment: Either the `.iso` file or the smaller `bin` tar file. I know no other way, but that does not mean there is none

Comment: the installation mechanisms for tl2105, 2016, 2017 are not substantially different, installing an obsolete version just because of a perceived problem with wget seems like a mistake

Comment: Probably I should have ran the .iso file at 2017  tl ... I'll give it a try next month !!!

Comment: How I can download this software?